# Eliminate [capabilities]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[capabilities](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/capabilities) is an undefined meta tag that does not appear to add value to any of the three questions using it.  One of the questions should probably use [permissions] or [file-permissions] instead. Recommend deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

### Done

Tag removed from all questions. Obvious meta tag is obvious.